# Pm2 startup issue with CENTOS 8 / SELinux

Tags: pm2, selinux, centos8

Please, do you know how resolve this issue ?
I searched everywhere without finding.

```
06:45 SELinux is preventing systemd from open access on the file /root/.pm2/pm2.pid. For complete SELinux messages run: sealert -l d84a5a0b-cfcf-4cb9-918a-c0952bf70600 setroubleshoot

06:45 pm2-root.service: Can't convert PID files /root/.pm2/pm2.pid O_PATH file descriptor to proper file descriptor: Permission denied systemd 2 

06:45 Failed to start PM2 process manager.
```

I have executed this command : sealert -l d84a5a0b-cfcf-4cb9-918a-c0952bf70600 setroubleshoot

```
Messages d'audit bruts 
type=AVC msg=audit(1591498085.184:7731): avc:  denied  { open } for  pid=1 comm="systemd" path="/root/.pm2/pm2.pid" dev="dm-0" ino=51695937 scontext=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:admin_home_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
```

PM2 Version : 4.4.0
NODE version : 12.18.0
CentOS Version : 8

my systemd service :

```
[Unit]
Description=PM2 process manager
Documentation=https://pm2.keymetrics.io/
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=root
LimitNOFILE=infinity
LimitNPROC=infinity
LimitCORE=infinity
Environment=PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
Environment=PM2_HOME=/root/.pm2
PIDFile=/root/.pm2/pm2.pid
Restart=on-failure

ExecStart=/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 resurrect
ExecReload=/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 reload all
ExecStop=/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 kill

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Thank you

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same issue. Were you able to solve it ?

Comment: Using forever...

Comment: Yeah, I considered it too... But I'm not done with this yet. I'm currently investigating on how to lift SELinux restrictions. It appears possible, as it was done for a similar issue : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-centos-8#step-6-%E2%80%93-setting-up-server-blocks-(optional). The command is a bit cryptic, though : `chcon -vR system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 /var/www/your_domain/`

Comment: I finally found it... I'm posting an answer here

Answer (score 6):

As said in the comments, I had the [exact same issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/604679/selinux-how-to-grant-read-access/604700#604700).

To solve this, just run the following commands as root after trying to start the PM2 service (in your case, this start attempt would be `systemctl start pm2-root`)

```
ausearch -c 'systemd' --raw | audit2allow -M my-systemd
semodule -i my-systemd.pp
```

This looks pretty generic, but it works. These lines were suggested by SELinux itself. To get them, I had to run the command `journalctl -xe` after trying to start the service

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. Edit the `systemd` file that starts `pm2` and specify an alternative location for the `pm2` PIDFile). You'll have to make two changes, one to tell `pm2` where to place the PIDFile, and one to tell `systemd` where to look for it. Replace the existing PIDFile line with the following two lines

```
Environment=PM2_PID_FILE_PATH=/run/pm2.pid
PIDFile=/run/pm2.pid
```

2. Create an SELinux rule that allows this particular behavior. You can do that exactly as Backslash36 suggest in their answer. If you want to create the policy file yourself rather than through `audit2allow`,the following should work, although then you have to compile it to a usable .pp file yourself.

```
module pm2 1.0;

require {
        type user_home_t;
        type init_t;
        class file read;
}

#============= init_t ==============
allow init_t user_home_t:file read;
```